# Egress data from GCP vm

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm familiar with the rule setting of GCP VM and could 
let traffic get through ingress port.

However, when I want to send data from the VM to my phone or laptop, even I already have a rule allowing data send to any ip from any egresss port, it still fails.

I can ping via both directions. 
However, iperf can only work via my phone to the VM, without getting any ACK. On the other direction, vm can't use iperf to any outsider.

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.

Update:

I might found out the reason.
I was using my phone over LTE network, so that the incoming traffic from VM is probably blocked by LTE provider.

Comment: Do you try the connection between you vm and laptop by  ping or telnet ?

Comment: Hi, I added in the description now.

Answer (score 0):

I tested myself with 2 instances in different networks, test1 in network1 and test2 in network2. Both instances have Debian GNU/Linux 9 and Iperf.

FW rule for test1:

Network: network1
Direction: ingress
IP allowed: “external-ip-of-test2”
Port allowed: 5001

FW rule for test2:

Network: network2
Direction: egress
IP allowed: “external-ip-of-test1”
Port allowed: 5001

I start listening on test1 with the command: $ iperf -s
Then I started the test in test2 with the command: $ iperf -c “external-ip-of-test1”

For me it worked perfectly.

Make sure that:

The firewall rule configurations has the same network as the VM.
You selected Egress as "Direction of traffic".
The TPC port that you are allowing is 5001 (is the default for iPerf).

I recommend you to put just the external ip of your laptop - mobile phone as allowed and avoid using the ip 0.0.0.0/0. Be sure that the priority is lower than 1000 in the firewall rule.

If the issue persist ensure that iPerf in your mobile phone - laptop is working fine.

Comment: Hi Jorge, thanks for the comment.
I tried it and found out iperf could work, both for internal and external.
However, when I want to use a random UDP port to transfer via socket, it didnt' work. For instance,  simple client/server in python could't work even between two VMs. Sample code: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

Comment: Is your "random UDP port" opened on the firewall (ingress and egress) as my Iperf example?

Comment: Yes, I have that specific port open, and another rule opening all the ports as well. Both with priority higher than 1000 (number smaller than 1000).